# Generate unique numbers in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

In php there's a function called [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). It generates unique identifiers based on the current time. I was wondering if something like that was available in ActionScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[There is no built-in way to generate a true UUID](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/UIDUtil.html#createUID%28%29) in ActionScript. You can get something good enough via

```
import mx.utils.UIDUtil;
var uuid:String = UIDUtil.createUID();
```

Comment: This is not pure ActionScript as `mx.utils.UIDUtil' is actually in the Flex framework. Thus this won't work in pure AS projects

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of snippets and libs I've found to do this is *pure* ActionScript

- http://code.google.com/p/actionscript-uuid
- http://snipplr.com/view/45247/